# How can the agents be shown inside a node before the simulation starts?

Tags: containers, population

For a project work I have to simulate the unloading of containers from a ship. I created a rectangular node and I would like to see the cointainer already on the node before the simulation starts. How can I do that? What should I put on the source "arrivals defines by"?

Thank you!

I wanted to use a population of agents but I think the limited PLE version of Anylogic doesn't make me create one.

Answer (score 0):

in the source you can select "location of arrival" there you select "Network/GIS node" and then you can select the rectangular node.

Nothing to do with arrivals defined by.. but go read the help documentation to understand what all the properties mean